# Convert single-module gradle project to multi-module

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, multi-module

With the spring boot-based GRADLE project which i generate using the spring initializer, how do i turn this single-module project into multi-module? Any good tutorial to demonstrate this.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html?